# Install php7 mash with apt-get install

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, php-7, mhash

Is it possible to install [mhash](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mhash.php) with `apt-get`?

I've tried `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mhash`, but this doesn't work.

[Php document](http://php.net/manual/en/mhash.installation.php) says that I must compile PHP with `--with-mhash[=DIR]` parameter, but I wish I don't have to compile php7.0 from source.

Because I've installed php7.0 by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7). I wish I don't want to reinstall php7.0.